# CK Editor's Edit Content change into readonly for specific words

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am using CK Editor 4.4.7. I have the below content edited in my Ck Editor.

```
Dear {{USER-NAME}},

When your payment is successful on the payment gateway, you will see an order confirmation message on your screen with a unique PaisaPay ID for your transaction. You will also see your order details in My PaisaPay.
Order ID : {{ORDER-ID}}

Total Items : {{TOTAL-ITEMS}}
```

In this content i don't want the user to edit the contents inside the `{{...}}`,which means change that contents into readonly? Is it Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it is possoble,
visit,

http://ckeditor.com/addon/placeholder

using [Placeholder plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/placeholder) you can change particular text into readonly mode...